# Ramadan Taraweeh At Home

Tags: ramadan

I am in the United States (Atlanta, GA) and while all the local Masjid's followed Saudi and did taraweeh tonight, however I was looking for an actual sighting. With no sighting news, I decided to read Witr and not lead taraweeh tonight at home since there were no reports.

However, 50 min later, the moon was sighted in California and was too late to perform taraweeh.

What would I need to do in this case in regards to taraweeh? I will be fasting tomorrow.

Comment: So what are you following? Local sighting? Global sighting? Regional sighting? By naked eye only a sighting in California was possible yesterday. If you've decided to fast according global sighting you could have joined a congregation in a mosque. However it is not necessary to pray taraweeh in a mosque you can do it at home as I've already explained in [Is it obligatory to pray taraweeh in the mosque?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32602/13438).

Comment: I was following nation sighting and when I found out that the moon was sighted in California I had already read witr.

Comment: Also my local Masjids were not holding community taraweeh. Only the imams themselves. (Not 100% Proven)

Comment: If I got you right your question is how to go ahead and pray taraweeh after having prayer witr? In that case your question title and tags are missing the target, else you would have found answers on the site (see for example [Is it okay to pray tahajjud after witr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25294/is-it-okay-to-perform-tahajjud-after-witir/25990?)).

Comment: @Medi1Saif I was more asking about like if there is anything I need to do in place of me not praying the taraweeh due to moon sighting times. Anyway, someone had already answered the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The taraweeh prayer during Ramadan is a confirmed sunnah of the prophet, but it is not considered obligatory. If you missed it then you missed it, but there is no sin on you for that and there is no need to make it up later.